# Javascript count the duplicate array values until it changes

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this is a duplicate or a dumb question!

Basically, I need to get the count for duplicate values in an array until the next value changes. I can't use reduce() in my project, so any plain JS would be helpful.

let array = [a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b,c,c,c,a,d,d];

Results:
a:3,
b:5,
c:3,
a:1,
d:2

I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: You can use `forEach`

Comment: `{a:3, b:5, c:3, a:1, d:2}` about the letter `a` is not possible, since JS will override `a:1` and remove priewer `a:3`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to get the desired result.

```
/([a-z])\1*/gi
```

[image]

```js
let array = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "d", "d"];
const result = array
  .join("")
  .match(/([a-z])\1*/gi)
  .map((s) => `${s[0]}${s.length}`);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice way using `Regex`; but to match same result try to do `Object.fromEntries(result.map(charCount=>[charCount.slice(0,1),charCount.slice(1)]))` However it will override `a` as mentionned in comments

Answer (score 0):

Simply *loop* over `chars` and check if `char` in `dict` then *increment* it else set it to *1*;

```js
let chars =  ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'd'];
const dic={}
for(char of chars){
    if(char in dic){
        dic[char]++;
    }else{
        dic[char]=1;
    }
}
console.log(dic);//{a: 4, b: 5, c: 3, d: 2}
```

Answer (score -1):

Run iteration over array elements. Find the next non-equal current character's position. then difference the two indexes you will find the current character's continuous last position. Increase the iteration so you need not worry about multiple counts. If no non-equal character found, then the size of the sub-array is the rest of the main array size.

```
let ara = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'd'];

let index = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < ara.length; i++) {

    let char = ara[i];
    let size = 0;

    let nextIndex = ara.findIndex(
        (a, index) => a !== char && index > i);
    if (nextIndex < 0) {
        size = ara.length - i;
        i = ara.length - 1;
    } else {
        size = nextIndex - i;
        i = nextIndex - 1;
    }
    console.log(char + ' ' + size);
```