# I would like to count matching neighboring items in an array and return the count

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting

I have an array and i would like to find all neighboring matches and count them, then return the count, performed in a loop like .map() so it wont be necessary to store a memory of what was counted beyond the current element. i need to use this number of current elements to reserve enough spaces for each group of elements

```
array = [ball, batter, batter, amount, amount, github, github, github, account, account, account, account, account, account, account, github, github, github]
```

example of desired results from this array would be: on first loop would return 1, second loop would return 2, then 2, then 3, then 7, then 3

and this count would be used as a variable to reserve space, something like

```
number to reserve: count
```

so through each loop, the variable `count` would be changed and updated to the current elements count, and the loop that counts would not stop until the next element is not a match for the current element, and the variable `count` will also not be available for use until all concurrent matches are found, so if i put `console.log(count)` at the end of the function i would get each number output individually

Comment: What do you mean by _concurrent matches_?  I feel like you can just delete the word _concurrent_ from your question.  In computing, _concurrent_ typically means something entirely different to the way in which you're trying to use that word.  Did you mean _consecutive_?

Comment: Can you explain what actually problem you solve

Comment: i have a blank space, and i need to know how many spaces each individual word needs, ball needs one space reserved. batter needs two spaces reserved. amount needs two spaces reserved

Comment: why not just use a dictionary and count in a single loop.

Comment: Check ansewers on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5667888/87713)

Comment: thanks @decpk I was having trouble constructing the loop, i couldnt get my head around how to do it. @FFire those solutions count elements wherever they appear in the array, i only want to count neighboring groups, so in my example `github` should show two two groups of three, not one group of six. the numbers should also appear in the order of the groups they represent (not alphabetical)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily count the consecutive string in an array as:

```js
const array = ["ball", "batter", "batter", "amount", "amount", "github", "github", "github", "account", "account", "account", "account", "account", "account", "account", "github", "github", "github"]

const result = [];
let last = array[0], lastSameIndex = 0;
for (let i = 1; i < array.length; ++i) {
  if (array[i] !== last) {
    result.push(i - lastSameIndex);
    lastSameIndex = i;
    last = array[i];
  }
}
result.push(array.length - lastSameIndex);

console.log(result);
```

---

Let's declare some initial values as

`last = array[0]`, so `last = "ball"`, and `lastSameIndex = 0`

So we have to start from the index `1` and we only have to consider a single case where the two elements are not equal i.e. `array[i] !== last`. If they are not equal then we have to push the count of same element till now as:

```
result.push(i - lastSameIndex);
```

Now, we have to update the new value and index i.e. `last` element from where we have to count that element again.

```
lastSameIndex = i;
last = array[i];
```

So far so good, but we also have to handle a case where the loop ends, In this case we have to push the count of last element from where the count started i.e. `last` started or `lastSameIndex` till the last element.

```
result.push(array.length - lastSameIndex);
```

**`Second solution`**

```js
const array = [ "ball", "batter", "batter", "amount", "amount", "github", "github", "github", "account", "account", "account", "account", "account", "account", "account", "github", "github", "github"];

let lastStr = "",
  num = 0;
const result = array
  .map((s) => {
    if (lastStr !== s) {
      lastStr = s;
      num = num === 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return num;
  })
  .join("")
  .match(/(\d)\1*/g)
  .map((s) => s.length);
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Explain the principle...

Comment: @decpk Wonderful!

Comment: @Breakingnotsobad I've tried. Please have a loop and added another solution also.

Comment: Good two ways, but in the second it would be more efficient if you use regex directly, as I did in my answer!

Answer (score 2):

So loop each item, if it's not equal to the last item, push `1`, else add `1` to the last number in the array.

```js
const items = ["ball", "batter", "batter", "amount", "amount", "github", "github", "github", "account", "account", "account", "account", "account", "account", "account", "github", "github", "github"]

const results = [];

items.forEach((item, i) => {
    if (items[i - 1] !== item) return results.push(1);

    const last = results.length - 1;
    results[last] = results[last] + 1;
});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Dude, your solution is not what OP wants. Output should be `[1, 2, 2, 3, 7, 3]` not `[1, 2, 2, 6, 7]`. You are just taking a count.

Comment: Oops, you're right! Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

- Try to join the array into string seperated with comma by `array.join(",")`: `ball,batter,batter,amount,amount,github,github,github`
- Use **regex**: `/([a-z]+,)\1*/gi` to match same repeated word Gives:
  `['ball,', 'batter,batter,', 'amount,amount,', 'github,github,github,...]`
- Count how many word in each string of array by using `s.split(',').length-1`

***Script:***

```js
array.join(",").match(/([a-z]+,)\1*/gi).map((s) => `${s.split(',').length-1}`);
```

***Result:*** `['1', '2', '2', '3', '7', '2']`

Comment: Isn't this is like the solution from this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68124835/javascript-count-the-duplicate-array-values-until-it-changes/68124886#)

Comment: AFAIT, But this solution will be not so efficient because regex will have to do much more work as compared to direct string comparison

Comment: Yeah, it is the same, but in this we dealing with words not chars, but the same idea!

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not efficient as if we did it with for-loop and the words should not contain `,` comma!

Comment: Yeah, I agree but this can be an alternate solution. Great

Comment: Yeah, An alternate but not perfect as your answer!